# Ionic framework Back button fade out in navigation bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a weird problem is the Back button on Navigation bar disappear if the entry point of the view is by pass certain page.

My case is
Everything start with "Home" page. And I have a "brand" page and a "product" page.

Case 1
Home -> Product (No Problem)
Home -> Brand -> Product (Back icon will be fade out at Product page in such case)

I am not sure which part goes wrong. I checked app.js, code pattern of each controller and templates and some sample project on github.

Anyone encounter similar problem before?

Code could be posted, but at first I need to know where to start with.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is hierarchy of each tab. For example:

```
Search Tab (abstract) -> Step 1 -> Step 2 -> Step 3
Account Tab (abstract) -> Manage -> Link -> Transfer
```

Each tab has its own history (you can learn more about `ui-router`). So when you switch tab you are switching history.

You can manually hide back button if its giving you trouble. Just do this..

```
<nav-page hide-back-button="true">
```

You can also create custom button to fulfill your need. Please refer to ionic documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally people from ionic forum found that I added a **nav-clear** in one of the tags and make the button disappear.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: A bit more detail would be handy. :-)